# download overleaf project source via script

Tags: tex

How can I download the source of an overleaf project with a command line script? I want to make regular backups of the source and it'd be better if I could automate the download instead of having to do it through the web interface every time. I'm not aware of any API that would allow me to do that, is there any?

I know that an ideal solution would probably use git-overleaf integration for proper version control and that's what I do for my personal projects, but for some projects I have to work with collaborators who find git too confusing and do not want to enable the git features to avoid possible confusions between the git history and overleaf's history, so that's not an option.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look into scripts that download zip archive of your project, for example [overleafv2-git-integration-unofficial](https://github.com/tobiasBora/overleafv2-git-integration-unofficial)

This python script will download zip of your project, extract it, and delete the zip. It offers basic git functionality albeit largely experimental.

```
Sample usage:

overleafv2-git --email=your@email --password=yourpass --message="commit message" project-URL
```